# Prolog - Puzzle 8

Tags: list, prolog, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have to make a prolog progam that solves the puzzle 8. It's for my programming club in school that I'm in just for fun. I'm new to Prolog  - I'm having a hard time.
Here's my code:

```
puzzle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]).

%%up
c([0, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X4, X2, X3, 0, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
c([X1, 0, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X5, X3, X4, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
c([X1, X2, 0, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X6, X4, X5, 0, X7, X8, X9]).
c([X1, X2, X3, 0, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X7, X5, X6, 0, X8, X9]).
c([X1, X2, X3, X4, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X8, X6, X7, 0, X9]).
c([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, 0, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X9, X7, X8, 0]).

%%right
d([0, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X2, 0, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
d([X1, 0, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X3, 0, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
d([X1, X2, X3, 0, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X5, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
d([X1, X2, X3, X4, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X6, 0, X7, X8, X9]).
d([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, 0, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X8, 0, X9]).
d([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, 0, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X9, 0]).

%%down
b([X1, X2, X3, 0, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [0, X2, X3, X1, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
b([X1, X2, X3, X4, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, 0, X3, X4, X2, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
b([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, 0, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, 0, X4, X5, X3, X7, X8, X9]).
b([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, 0, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, 0, X5, X6, X4, X8, X9]).
b([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, 0, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, 0, X6, X7, X5, X9]).
b([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, 0], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, 0, X7, X8, X6]).

%%left
e([X1, 0, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [0, X1, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
e([X1, X2, 0, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, 0, X2, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
e([X1, X2, X3, 0, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X5, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
e([X1, X2, X3, X4, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X6, 0, X7, X8, X9]).
e([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, 0, X8, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X8, 0, X9]).
e([X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, 0, X9], [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X9, 0]).

%%prints puzzle
affiche_puzzle :-
    puzzle(Puzzle),
    printe(Puzzle).
printe([]).
printe([H1,H2,H3|Puzzle]) :-
    format('~w ~w ~w~n', [H1, H2, H3]),
    printe(Puzzle).
```

Now I have to create mov_legal(C1, M, P, C2) --> c2 is obtained from configuration c1, doing the move M, moving the piece P.
Here's one expected result:

```
?- mov_legal([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 6], M, P, C).
M = c,
P = 6,
C = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0] ;
M = b,
P = 3,
C = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 6] ;
...
```

I would be grateful if you help me!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to change the predicate of your configuration:

```
%%up
legal_move([0, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], c, 4, [X4, X2, X3, 0, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9]). 
legal_move([X1, 0, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9], c, 5, [X1, X5, X3, X4, 0, X6, X7, X8, X9]).
...
```

Although if you don't want to, or can't for any reason, you could do something like the following:

```
legal_move(C1,c,C2) :- c(C1,C2). %% left
legal_move(C1,d,C2) :- d(C1,C2). %% right
legal_move(C1,b,C2) :- b(C1,C2). %% down
legal_move(C1,e,C2) :- e(C1,C2). %% up
legal_move(C1,C,P,C2) :- legal_move(C1,C,C2), nth1(P,C2,0).
```

Just in case you didn't noticed. You've also made some copy paste errors in your configuration. (your left predicates are partly wrong)